# Why do we delete s from the queue?

Tags: algorithm, queue, breadth-first-search

I am given the following algorithms:

```
Breadthfirstsearch(G,s)

for each u ∈ V \ {s}
     color[u]<-white
     d[u]<-oo
     p[u]<-Ø
color[s]<-gray
d[s]<-0
p[s]<-Ø
Q<-Ø // Q is a queue
Insert(Q,s)
while Q ≠ Ø
       u<-Delete(Q)
       for each v  ∈ Adj(u)
          if color[v]=white then
             color[v]<-gray
             d[v]=d[u]+1
             p[v]<-u
             Insert(Q,v)

       color[u]<-black

Delete(Q)
x<-Q[head[Q]]
if head[Q]=length[Q] then
   head[Q]<-1
else
   head[Q]<-head[Q]+1
return x
```

In my notes,there is the following example:

[image]

At the beginning it is like that:

[image]

and after the first "for",it is like that:

[image]

I haven't understood,why we delete s from Q.

With the command  u<-Delete(Q),u becomes the value of s, and the variable head[Q] changes in the function,but it does not change in the main program,or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The name `delete()` for the method is a bit misguiding, maybe a better name would be `deleteAndReturnHead()`. The idea is the function returns the "old" head of the queue (`s` in your exampe), and set the new head to the next element (`a` in your example).

The function `Delete()` is using the fact that the implementation of your queue is a [circular array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). You set the element to return (which is `s` in the example), and then you simply advance a pointer that indicates where the queue starts, to the next element. The circular part is in:

```
if head[Q]=length[Q] then
   head[Q]<-1
```

If the pointer to the head is the last index, move the pointer to the head of the array, which is the next element to be inserted.

Since Q is passed by reference (and not copied each time you pass it), any change to it will be reflected to the calling environment (the BFS procdure) as well.

Comment: I understand!!!So,should the function be like that?



`Delete(Q,&head,length){ `
   ` x=Q[head]`;
   ` if head=length{`
        `head=1`
   }
   `else`
       `head=head+1`;
`return x`
}


?

Comment: @evinda You are missing a sanity check to verify the queue is not empty, but other than that - it seems to be correct